# how to wrap wpf datagrid columns text when it is populated using a List dynamically?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, word-wrap

I have an xaml like:

```
<GroupBox Header="groupBox1" Height="174" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,38,0,0" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="285">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid x:Name="caseListGrid">
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
</GroupBox>
```

and in the .cs file i have a function:

```
private void LoadDataGrid()
{
    caseElementList = new List<CaseElement>();
    caseElementList.Clear();

    //add 1st element
    caseElementList.Add(new CaseElement
    {
        CaseName = "First Name",
        Description = "Recently I came across the need to customize the look of the standard message box in the application. To do this I’ve decided to create a new class named WPFMessageBox"
    });

    //add second
    caseElementList.Add(new CaseElement
    {
        CaseName = "Second Name",
        Description = "Recently I came across the need to customize the look of the standard message box in the application. To do this I’ve decided to create a new class named WPFMessageBox"
    });

    caseElementList.Add(new CaseElement
    {
        CaseName = "Third Name",
        Description = "Recently I came across the need to customize the look of the standard message box in the application. To do this I’ve decided to create a new class named WPFMessageBox"
    });


    DataGrid dGrid = new DataGrid();                        
    dGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;            
    dGrid.ItemsSource = caseElementList;
    this.caseListGrid.Children.Add(dGrid);
}
```

here in the function i have created a List of custom case objects. Then i have assigned the list to the datagrid (after creating the datagrid).

But as because i have not added styles in the datagrid.. and the texts are very big. So, 
it is expanding in a scrollview.

But i want to display them using text wrapping. So, can anyone give me any solution??

I have found that using textblock it can be solved. But i can't figured out how i can add textblocks in that datagrid as because i am creating this dynamically..!!

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Do not `AutoGenerateColumns` and specify the columns yourself.

Solution 2: Subscribe to the [AutoGeneratingColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event and change the column to something that wraps (e.g. using the [ElementStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.elementstyle%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property of the column).

Comment: i have created a function which receive the eventhandler "DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e" for the event "AutoGeneratingColumn". Here is my new code:                                                                  private void AutoGeneratingColumnEventHandler(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            string header = e.Column.Header.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Header:: " + header);
        }

Comment: But i can only hold the headers only. But not the other list of rows... can u give me some suggestion of how can i write the styles...